# Combine variable with string in a input name of form in PHP

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP, and I'm trying to write a iteration that post a value to another page with auto-increment, this is the code:

```
$j = 1;
    if (isset($emails))
    {
      foreach ($emails as $email)
      {
        echo "<input type='text' name='email_[$j]' value='{$email['email']}' form='saveForm'><br>";
        $j++;
      }
    }
```

Then on the other page, I could access the value by

>

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$email_count; $i++)
{
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email_'.$i]);
  }
```

The error shows

> Undefined index: email_4

So I'm pretty sure it's problem of the first code that should pass the value as "email_1", anyone knows what is correct way to combine the string and variable in the input name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code  `echo "<input type='text' name='email_[$j]' value='{$email['email']}' form='saveForm'><br>";` makes the name of the input to be `email_[1]`.
Change it to `name='email_$j'` or `name='email_{$j}'` and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks! It works! I tried in a new page and it turned the problem was caused by nested forms, anyway, thank you!